# What is the effect of rationalization on this equation?

Tags: calculus, limits

I know this seems a silly question, but I really don't get it.

Considering this equation,
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt x+1}}$$
So when $x=1$, $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$

By rationalization (multiplying by $\frac{{\sqrt x-1}}{{\sqrt x-1}}$), we know that the above equation equal to 
$$f(x) = \frac{{\sqrt x-1}}{x-1}$$
This time when $x=1$, $f(x)=\frac{0}{0}=intermediate$

If we plot two graph for these two equation (which is the same equation), is there **discontinuity** when $x=1$ in the first situation?
This makes me feel contradicting. Can anyone explain it to me?

> Similar question:
>   [Are these two functions equal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787269/are-these-two-functions-equal)

Comment: Rationalization requires that you multiply by a quantity that is well-defined. When $x=1$, $\sqrt{x} - 1$ is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you multiplies by $\dfrac{{\sqrt x-1}}{{\sqrt x-1}}$, there was a hidden condition for $\sqrt{x}-1 \neq 0$ (of denominator), you were apparently dividing by $0$,which isn't allowed in mathematics.You missed it here.

It is the same saying $x=\dfrac {1}{\frac{1}{x}}$, which is true, but discontinuous at $x=0$. (Since we can't take reciprocal of $0$.)

In short, your rationalisation says :

$\dfrac{1}{2}= \dfrac{1}{2} \times \dfrac{0}{0} = \dfrac{0}{0} =$ Undefined.

While the fact is, you can no doubt multiply by $0$, but can never divide by $0$.

Answer (score 0):

For $x\neq1$ we have $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt x+1} = \dfrac{{\sqrt x-1}}{x-1}$ and this is trivial that you got $\dfrac00$ with $x=1$ in two expressions.

In view of functions topic, two functions $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ are **equal** if

(1) $D_f=D_g$.

(2) $f(x)=g(x)$

so $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt x+1} = \dfrac{{\sqrt x-1}}{x-1}$ shows second condition is valid for $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt x+1}$ and $g(x) = \dfrac{{\sqrt x-1}}{x-1}$. But the first not since $D_f=[0,\infty)$ while $D_g=[0,\infty)-\{1\}$, so $D_f\neq D_g$.

Comment: When x=1 in the first condition, why not f(x) = 1/2?